# Pagination with constantly updating data

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, pagination

I have to implement pagination in a table whose records updates frequently.
I have a sorting criteria based on Priority, but the Priority of records can keep on changing and they needs to be shift accordingly.
There is a socket event which notifies about Priority change in action to that the record placement is changed.

This needs to be achieved via Infinite scrolling.

Please suggest something